# Am I creating a temporary c struct and sending it through socket?

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, struct, syntax

I have managed to send c struct over the socket.

But, I have read that there are two ways of doing this:

1. by dynamically allocation the memory and filling the struct elements then returning a pointer to the structure
2. Create a temporary struct and filling the struct members then returning the content of the struct.

My code here:

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct EnQuery {
    char type[7];
    char table_name[53];
    char columns[5][53];
    struct Values {
        char doc[129];
        char key[2][206];
        char iv[17];
        char td[53];
        char s[206];
    }values;
    struct EnCondition {
        int k;
        char attr[53];
        char val[53];
    }enCondition;
    int len;
    int  rn;
}EnQuery;
```

and it is declared in the main():

```
struct EnQuery * ieq;
ieq = (EnQuery *)malloc(sizeof(EnQuery));
strcpy(ieq->type,"INSERT");
strcpy(ieq->table_name,"table_name");
strcpy(ieq->columns[0],"Hello");
strcpy(ieq->columns[1],"hi");
strcpy(ieq->columns[2],"an");
strcpy(ieq->columns[3],"nyung");
strcpy(ieq->columns[4],"haseyo");
strcpy(ieq->values.doc,"doc");
strcpy(ieq->values.key[0],"key1");
strcpy(ieq->values.key[1],"key2");
strcpy(ieq->values.iv,"iv");
strcpy(ieq->values.td,"td");
strcpy(ieq->values.s,"s");
ieq->enCondition.k = htonl(1);
strcpy(ieq->enCondition.attr,"attr");
strcpy(ieq->enCondition.val,"val");
ieq->len = htons(1);
ieq->rn = htons(2);
```

and it uses this function to send:

```
send_struct(&sfd,ieq);
```

The content of send_struct():

```
send_struct(int * sfd, struct EnQuery *ieq) {
    int n;
    char buff[256];

    if(n = read(*sfd,buff,256) > 0) {
        struct EnQuery eq;
        eq = *ieq;
        printf("eq.type = %s\n",eq.type);
        printf("eq.table_name = %s\n",eq.table_name);
        printf("eq.columns = {%s,%s,%s,%s,%s}\n",eq.columns[0],eq.columns[1],eq.columns[2],eq.columns[3],eq.columns[4]);
        printf("eq.values.doc = %s\n",eq.values.doc);
        printf("eq.values.key = {%s,%s}\n",eq.values.key[0],eq.values.key[1]);
        printf("eq.values.iv = %s\n",eq.values.iv);
        printf("eq.values.td = %s\n",eq.values.td);
        printf("eq.values.s = %s\n",eq.values.s);
        printf("eq.enCondition.k = %d\n",ntohs(eq.enCondition.k));
        printf("eq.enCondition.attr = %s\n",eq.enCondition.attr);
        printf("eq.enCondition.val = %s\n",eq.enCondition.val);
        printf("eq.len = %d\n",ntohs(eq.len));
        printf("eq.rn = %d\n",ntohs(eq.rn));
        send(*sfd,&eq,sizeof(struct EnQuery),0);
    }
}
```

On the receiving side:

```
recv_struct(int sfd){
    struct EnQuery eq;
    FILE* instream = fdopen(sfd,"r");
    if(fread(&eq,sizeof(struct EnQuery),1,instream) != 1) {
        error("fread(1)");
    }
    printf("eq.type = %s\n",eq.type);
    printf("eq.table_name = %s\n",eq.table_name);
    printf("eq.columns = {%s,%s,%s,%s,%s}\n",eq.columns[0],eq.columns[1],eq.columns[2],eq.columns[3],eq.columns[4]);
    printf("eq.values.doc = %s\n",eq.values.doc);
    printf("eq.values.key = {%s,%s}\n",eq.values.key[0],eq.values.key[1]);
    printf("eq.values.iv = %s\n",eq.values.iv);
    printf("eq.values.td = %s\n",eq.values.td);
    printf("eq.values.s = %s\n",eq.values.s);
    eq.enCondition.k = ntohs(eq.enCondition.k);
    printf("eq.enCondition.k = %d\n",eq.enCondition.k);
    printf("eq.enCondition.attr = %s\n",eq.enCondition.attr);
    printf("eq.enCondition.val = %s\n",eq.enCondition.val);
    eq.len = ntohs(eq.len);
    printf("eq.len = %d\n",eq.len);
    eq.rn = ntohs(eq.rn);
    printf("eq.rn = %d\n",eq.rn);
}
```

Since I have been implementing by trial and error, 
I am not sure what exact i am doing here.

Which of the top is my code according to? is it sending as a linked binary format?

Can somebody elaborate what is happening with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically allocating the struct pointer is not required (as being done before send_struct()).
Temporary structure will also work fine. (send_struct(&sfd, &obj) where struct EnQuery obj;)

Socket data communication is basically array of bytes.
If you see your structure storage in memory, it is also array of bytes in memory.

Hence, dynamically allocating or temporary instance will only differ in the memory area where your structure data is stored (heap in first case, stack in second case).